# TabLayout -> View pager ->Fragments -> Recyclerview ,In this Hierarchy Recyclerview not visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I have a Tablayout and a view pager with 2 tabs. In the second tab, i need to show a fragment with some static view and a recyclerciew.I am able to see the static views but there is no view of recyclerview is visible. I have tried to debug, everything seems to be fine and the same fragment on attached to a drawer is also working fine but it's not working with view pager.

Comment: Try to give fix height of view page and also try to fix the height of RecyclerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line `mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));`to `mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));`

Comment: in logCats are you getting the error like `skipping layout no adapter attach` if not then issue is with your layout kindly post the layout too

Comment: try removing scroll View

Comment: i have added all the layout , please check

Comment: Even after removing scrollview,there is no change

Comment: you are not adding the element in `pgdParameters` list

Comment: thank you, u have saved my time.I dont know how did i miss that.